# TransactionScope Complete() doesn't commit the transaction before exiting the USING statement

Tags: c#, .net, transactionscope

I am experiencing this weird behavior where the transaction gets committed only when the `using` exits and not when calling `scope.Complete();`

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
       {
        scope.Complete();
           // data still doesn't show in db
       }
       // now shows in db
```

How do I commit the transaction before exiting the `using` statement?

Comment: Committable Transaction is the only transaction which provides options to commit or rollback http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.committabletransaction.aspx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.complete.aspx):

> The actual work of commit between the resources manager happens at the **End Using** statement if the TransactionScope object created the transaction.

So it doesn't look like you can truly commit the transaction before the using statement end.

Comment: The main reason is that it might be nested inside of another scope, so all you're saying is that "my work here is looking good" but a failure later on might still want to roll it back if it was part of a larger operation.