# Using powershell - how to prevent SQL from access the same record

Tags: sql, powershell

I want to run multiple instances of powershell to collect data from Exchange. In powershell, I use invoke-sqlcmd to run various SQL commands from powershell.

```
SELECT TOP 1 SmtpAddress FROM [MMC].[dbo].[EnabledAccounts]
where [location] = '$Location' and Script1 = 'Done' and (Script2 = '' or 
Script2 is null)
```

When running more than one script, I see both scripts accessing the same record. I know there's a way to update the record, to lock it, but not sure how to write it out. TIA:-)

Answer (score 1):

The database management system (I'll assume SQL Server) will handle contention for you. Meaning, if you have two sessions trying to update the same set of records, SQL Server will block one session while the other completes. You don't need to do anything to explicitly make that happen. That said, it's a good idea to run your update in a transaction if you are applying multiple updates as a single unit; a single change occurs in an implicit transaction. The following thread talks more about transactions using `Invoke-SqlCmd`.

[Multiple Invoke-SqlCmd and Sql Server transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977650/multiple-invoke-sqlcmd-and-sql-server-transaction)